# React: How to correctly set new value in two dimensional array with useState()

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

See [here for a Codesandbox displaying my problem](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-sammet-srngq).

I'm new to React. I am trying to dynamically create a `svg` element based on user input. Im splitting up the individual words, calculating the width of these words, and push them into a `content` array.

Without using the `useState` React hook, this all works fine. The individual words get added. However, for some reason when using `useState`, the array is updated entirely different.

How can I make my (left) example from the Codesandbox work with the React `useState` hook and what am I getting wrong?

Comment: Too long for me to dig into, but the based approach I would make would be to see if the key pressed was "enter", then set the new state if that is true.

Comment: Also, you should be able to `useRef` to capture your dummy data, and utilize that all in the same update function, rather than parsing it out to two separate functions.